# Dilemma with TripIt integration

Tags: api, integration

We are trying to integrate TripIt with our web application for itinerary management. I created a new App and got api key & secret. But we want to use the employee's trip it account and retrieve their trips & create trip in their account. Now i have one dilemma, since i am using my api key & secret, i can able to retrieve trips created in my account, but i want to retrieve trips of whoever logged in with their tripit account, with my api key.

So in this scenario, i will ask for user's trip it credentials and is there a way i can get their trips using my api key? Any viable solution is welcome. If you clear me with the flow i can able to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (OAuth) API key and secret are issued for your **application**, not for your specific user account. What this means is that your application can be given permission to access the user's data. If you've ever worked with the Twitter or Facebook APIs, TripIt's API behaves much the same.

1. You [register an application](https://www.tripit.com/developer/create) through TripIt (sounds like you've already got this step down)
2. Using an [SDK of your choice](http://tripit.github.io/api/), you create endpoints in your code to handle the various steps in the [OAuth workflow](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/dancing-with-oauth-understanding-how-authorization-works/).

Here is a quick rundown of the workflow for OAuth 1.0, which TripIt uses.

- The user begins the process of connecting their TripIt account to your application
- Your application builds a request token URL and sends the user to TripIt's OAuth dialog, indicating the `callback_url`
- The OAuth dialog (on TripIt's site) prompts the user to accept or decline permissions
- If approved, they return to your site (`callback_url`) with a 'signed' request token as part of the query string
- A backend process, typically a simple CURL request, exchanges the request token for an access token to finalize the process
- You store the access token associated with the user in your database and use it for future requests against the API

If you happen to be using PHP, here is an [open source example application](https://github.com/stephenyeargin/tripit-share-php) to take a look at. It does not save the token to a database (just keeps it in the session), but you should be able to glean the basic idea from it.